# How to run tests with and without javascript in Codeception?

Tags: php, selenium, codeception

Using Codeception acceptance tests I need to check some behaviors with and without Javascript. Right now, using Seleniun I can run all tests with Javascript enabled, and using PhpBrowser I can run all tests without javascript. But how can I do for running some tests with javascript and some tests without javascript?

Comment: How about using 2 different suites and configuring one to use WebDriver and another to use PhpBrowser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codeception has several methods of sorting tests:. "groups" "environments" and "suites". Either environments or suites could be used to run tests acceptance tests with different drivers. You can create a new suite on the command line with

```
codecept generate suite mySuite
```

Then just modify mySuite.yml and you're good to go.